# Cannot update has a > DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exists i

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I no I am going to be slatted today but I have an issue I am trying to get the nextid for the id of a table. Surly in 2017 bound to be easier to do this in one line of linq.

```
 /// <summary>
/// Get the next ID number for the table name supplied.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tableName">The unique table name.</param>
/// <returns>The next ID integer.</returns>
public string GetNextId(string tableName)
{
        int nextId = -1;

        try
        {


            var q = from n in _sourceEntities.NextIDs where n.TableName == tableName select n;


            NextID nextIdEntity = q.ToList()[0];

            nextId =(int) nextIdEntity.NextID1;
            nextIdEntity.NextID1 = nextId + 1;

            SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("GetNextId failed.", ex);
        }

        return nextId.ToString();
    }
```

But for some reason I am getting the error.

> {"Unable to update the EntitySet 'NextID' because it has a
>   DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the
>    element to support the current
>   operation."}

I am not to sure what that means.

Comment: Looks like `NextIDs` is a database view. By the way, this isn't a concurrency-tolerant way of getting a next ID value.

Comment: @GertArnold I no this its cause of the old data I dont no a better way of doing it

Comment: It appears your definition for `NextID` has no provision for changes - how was it created?